# Predict next failure based on past failures CSV data, on Windows

Tags: windows, prediction

I have a data set of a unit containing a value at a particular time. The unit fails at a particular day and time i.e the value becomes 0.

My task is to predict when will this failure occur next.  Os is windows 10, data format is csv and I only want make the prediction once. output must be the date and time at which the unit will fail i.e the value will be 0 again. Can anyone suggest software to train and test the time data and predict. following is how the data set[image: example of data set] looks like

Comment: From your problem description, it appears that you need to model the frequency of failures, which means fitting a Poisson distribution to your data.  There are several packages for `R` that can calculate Poisson prediction intervals, such as `EnvStats`.

Comment: thank you for your reply,yes i want to model the frequency of failures. But is their any way i can do this using pandas.

Comment: I can't give you any suggestions regarding pandas.  You might ask a new question about this.

Comment: Can you suggest any other way to get started

Comment: Most statistical packages ought to be able to fit a Poisson distribution to your data.  You can find formulas to calculate prediction intervals online, given the Poisson distribution parameter.